# Setting a horizontal scrollView layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center" android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3" android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:text="Level 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

So I want to have same layout when user scrolls right. There will be again gridview and textviews with different images. However I could not achieve it even if I looked examples. I tried to convert it to Linear Layout but again I could not create scroolview.

In other words, I have a layout like this one:

[image: Layout]

And when user scrolls right I want to have another gridview that holds different images. When user scrolls nothing changes but just images. Any help?

Comment: do what? I can't understand what you are actually trying to ask. Can you edit your post and include an image of what you are hoping to achieve, and another of what you have currently? Perhaps with that we can get a better idea of what you are asking.

Comment: I uploaded a picture of my current layout.

Comment: your image is not located at a public link, we can't see it.

Comment: yes, and it seems to me like you are looking for [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to make it possible to scroll your images in GridView horizontally. You can't achieve it with ScrollView. Try to use [TwoWayGridLayout](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview). Or you can use [ViewPager and Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). Choose one that is more convenient for your purposes.